# Markdown syntax not working within \multicol environment

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, footnotes

For extending footnotes over two columns, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462347/how-to-force-a-footnote-to-extend-over-both-columns-in-a-twocolumn-article?noredirect=1&lq=1 recommends `\usepackage{multicol}` instead of the `twocolumn` document option.

Although this works for pure *LaTeX* documents, it will not work for generating *PDF* output by *RMarkdown* and `pandoc` when having *Markdown*-formatted elements within the *multicol* environment as in:

```
---
title: Sample Document
header-includes: \usepackage{multicol}
output: pdf_document
---

\begin{multicols}{2}
# First section
\end{multicols}
```

What could be a possibility to achieve footnotes extending over two columns when using *RMarkdown*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the `\begin` and `\end` commands with blank lines. If that doesn't work, then mark them as LaTeX snippets like so:

````markdown
```{=latex}
\begin{multicols}{2}
```

# First section

```{=latex}
\end{multicols}
```
````